# Python create indented string from a list

Tags: python

I have a list of table of contents that I'd like to create into an indented string

```
list = ['1. Section', '1.1 Subsection', '1.1.1 Subsubsection', '1.1.2 Subsubsection', '2. Section', '2.1 Subsection', '2.1.1 Subsubsection', '2.1.2 Subsubsection', '2.2 Subsection', '2.2.1 Subsubsection']
```

And the desired result is this:

```
1. Section
    1.1 Subsection
        1.1.1 Subsubsection
        1.1.2 Subsubsection
2. Section
    2.1 Subsection
        2.1.1 Subsubsection
        2.1.2 Subsubsection
    2.2 Subsection
        2.2.1 Subsubsection
```

I've tried this:

```
toc = ''

for tocitem in list:
    if re.match('(\d+)\.', tocitem):
        toc += tocitem + '\n'
    elif re.match('(\d+)\.(\d+)', tocitem):
        toc += '\t' + tocitem + '\n'
    else:
        toc += '\t\t' + tocitem + '\n'
```

But the tabs are not recognized, that is I get this

```
1. Section
1.1 Subsection
1.1.1 Subsubsection
1.1.2 Subsubsection
2. Section
2.1 Subsection
2.1.1 Subsubsection
2.1.2 Subsubsection
2.2 Subsection
2.2.1 Subsubsection
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please put this as an answer so that I can accept it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse the order of `if re.match(...)` statements. All of your items pass the first test so the code never enters elif block.

Comment: I just put up the same as an answer.. :D

Comment: freakish was first ;) I'll give you guys an upvote for the effort :)

Comment: Ya he beat us by seconds to win the SO gold :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
toc = ''
for tocitem in list:
    if re.match('(\d+)\.(\d+)\.', tocitem):
        toc +=  '\t\t' + tocitem + '\n'
    elif re.match('(\d+)\.(\d+)', tocitem):
        toc += '\t' + tocitem + '\n'
    else:
        toc +=tocitem + '\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I use `lst` instead of `list`, because `list` is a function...

Next, for this to work you need to match first the longest
series of numbers, then work down to the shortest one.

```
toc = ''

for tocitem in lst:
    if re.match('(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)', tocitem):
        toc += '\t\t' + tocitem + '\n'
    elif re.match('(\d+)\.(\d+)', tocitem):
        toc += '\t' + tocitem + '\n'
    else:
        toc += tocitem + '\n'
```

And there's the output:

```
1. Section
        1.1 Subsection
                1.1.1 Subsubsection
                1.1.2 Subsubsection
2. Section
        2.1 Subsection
                2.1.1 Subsubsection
                2.1.2 Subsubsection
        2.2 Subsection
                2.2.1 Subsubsection
```

Now, this was regarding your question.
However, I would do this without `if`s, more systematically
as follows:

```
toc = ''

for tocitem in lst:
    s = re.match(r'\S+', tocitem).group(0)
    digits = [x for x in s.split('.') if x.strip() != '']
    toc += (len(digits) - 1) * 4 * ' ' + tocitem + '\n'
```

The regex simply finds the first section up until the space,
then splits on dot and take all the items which are not blank.

Answer (score 1):

The first if-condition matches also the other cases. So you have to switch the order, or make a more general approach:

```
toc = ''
for tocitem in list:
    number = tocitem.split()[0]
    toc += '\t' * number.strip('.').count('.') + tocitem + '\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

Really interesting question! here's a possible solution which assumes your data isn't sorted.

**python 2.x**:

```
import re
import random

# Unordered data!!!
lst = ['1. Section', '1.1 Subsection', '1.1.1 Subsubsection', '1.1.2 Subsubsection', '2. Section',
       '2.1 Subsection', '2.1.1 Subsubsection', '2.1.2 Subsubsection', '2.2 Subsection', '2.2.1 Subsubsection']
random.seed(1)
random.shuffle(lst)

# Creating TOC
data = {v[:v.rindex(" ")]: v for v in lst}
keys = sorted(data.keys(), key=lambda x: map(
    int, filter(lambda x: x, x.split('.'))))

toc = ''
for k in keys:
    number = data[k].split()[0]
    toc += '\t' * number.strip('.').count('.') + k + '\n'

print toc
```

Comment: I had 3 lists that I merged and sorted using `list(heapq.merge(sections, subsections, subsubsections))` were `sections`, `subsections` and `subsubsections` are appropriate lists :) But this looks interesting :)

Comment: @dingo_d Fair enough, I just wanted to provide a different answer to the other good ones ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Given the sorted list with section titles:

```
li = ['1. Section', '1.1 Subsection', '1.1.1 Subsubsection', '1.1.2 Subsubsection', '2. Section', '2.1 Subsection', '2.1.1 Subsubsection', '2.1.2 Subsubsection', '2.2 Subsection', '2.2.1 Subsubsection']
```

You can do:

```
print '\n'.join(['\t'*(len(re.findall(r"(\d+)", s))-1)+s for s in li])
```

Prints:

```
1. Section
    1.1 Subsection
        1.1.1 Subsubsection
        1.1.2 Subsubsection
2. Section
    2.1 Subsection
        2.1.1 Subsubsection
        2.1.2 Subsubsection
    2.2 Subsection
        2.2.1 Subsubsection
```

Given a random order list that you want to sort first:

```
li=['2.1.2 Subsubsection', '2.1.1 Subsubsection', '1.1.1 Subsubsection', '1. Section', '2. Section', '1.1 Subsection', '2.2 Subsection', '2.2.1 Subsubsection', '2.1 Subsection', '1.1.2 Subsubsection']
```

You can sort and indent in one loop without a regex:

```
for n, s in sorted([(ni, si) for ni, _, si in [x.partition(' ') for x in li]]):
    print '\t'*(len([e for e in n.split('.') if e])-1)+n, s
```

Prints:

```
1. Section
    1.1 Subsection
        1.1.1 Subsubsection
        1.1.2 Subsubsection
2. Section
    2.1 Subsection
        2.1.1 Subsubsection
        2.1.2 Subsubsection
    2.2 Subsection
        2.2.1 Subsubsection
```